# pandas apply with numpy interp, dimension problems

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, interpolation, apply

I want to interpolate measurements made at a dynamic sets of frequencies into a fixed set of frequencies. I use Python 3.7 with pandas.apply and numpy.interp:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'m1':[2.,3.],
               'm2':[4.,6.],
               'm3':[2.,3.],
               'shift':[1.1,1.2]})
print (df)
#     m1  m2   m3  shift
# 0  2.0   4  2.0    1.1
# 1  3.0   6  3.0    1.2

freqs =np.array([10.,20.,30.])

def myfunction(x):
  newfreqs = freqs*x[-1]
  result = np.interp(freqs,newfreqs,x[:-1])
  return result

print(df.apply(myfunction, axis=1,raw=True))
```

When I run the code I get the error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 2), indices imply (4, 2)
```

If I change one of the *input columns to int-type*, f.ex.

```
'f2':[4,6]
```

then *there is no error and the correct answer* is returned.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to return an array, which doesn't reduce. You can instead return a list of the values.

```
def myfunction(x):
    newfreqs = freqs*x[-1]
    result = np.interp(freqs, newfreqs, x[:-1])
    return [*result]

df.apply(myfunction, axis=1, raw=True)
#0    [2.0, 3.6363636363636367, 2.5454545454545454]
#1                                  [3.0, 5.0, 4.5]
#dtype: object
```

---

If you need the interpolated DataFrame, then perhaps:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(df.apply(myfunction, axis=1 ,raw=True).tolist(),
             columns=df.columns[0:3]).add_suffix('_interp')
#   m1_interp  m2_interp  m3_interp
#0        2.0   3.636364   2.545455
#1        3.0   5.000000   4.500000
```

Comment: Beautiful! Solved the problem 100%. Thank you.